# Byte size value in file different than number of bytes actually in file

Tags: node.js, c, binary, buffer

I have two versions of a .txt file, one of which is in binary and the other one which is just plain text. The plain text file has three floating point numbers on each line with a total of 23557 lines. The binary version of the plain text file just takes all of those floating point numbers and rewrites them to a different .txt file in a binary format.

So if the size of each double is 8 bytes, and if there's 3 floating point numbers per line, then there should be 24 bytes per line. In total, the binary version of the .txt file should then be 565368 bytes (24*23557).

Using nodejs, I obtain a buffer for the binary .txt file using

```
buffer = fs.readFileSync("./binary.txt")
```

and then try to get the number of bytes in the buffer using

```
size1 = buffer.length
size2 = Buffer.byteLength(buffer)
```

However, size1 and size2 don't match the size that I calculated. I want to be able to loop through the buffer from start to finish, reading from the buffer in the following way:

```
while (i < size) {
    // each iteration reads 3 doubles, which is equivalent to one line from the plain text file
    double1 = buffer.readDoubleLE(i)
    double2 = buffer.readDoubleLE(i+8)
    double3 = buffer.readDoubleLE(i+16)
    console.log(double1, double2, double3)
    i += 24
}
```

The loop correctly prints out the data (so the first iteration of the loop reads three doubles from the buffer and prints them out, and these 3 values match the first three values in the plain text file), but the `size` variable is wrong. So I'll end up printing out each line of the file like I want, but then the loop will start printing out garbage numbers once the entire file has been printed. I can set the size variable myself, but I'd like to be able to determine this variable programmatically using the given file alone and given its structure (3 8-byte doubles per line).

Why does the value of `size` determined by nodejs not match the value of `size` that I calculated? How can I programmatically determine the correct `size` value without knowing the number of lines in the plain text file?

An aside:
I'm using the following simplified C loop to convert the plain .txt file to the binary one:

```
while(fscanf(fin, "%lf %lf %lf", &lat, &longitude, &skip) != EOF) {
      double buf[3] = {lat, long, skip};
      write(fd, buf, sizeof(double)*3);
    }
```

Edit:
I'm on Windows 10 using WSL2 for both node and C.

Comment: I am reading conflicting things. Is the file a txt-file (implying ASCII or some kind of text encoding) or is it binary (implying that "lines" don't make sense).

Comment: What platform are you on? Are you opening the output file in binary mode in the C program?

Comment: @Retired Ninja I'm on Windows. In the C program I open the output file by calling: ```open("output.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);```

Comment: @Cheatah there's two .txt files, one with ASCII text and the other with binary data. The "lines" refer to the lines in the ASCII version. I essentially obtained the "binary" version by creating a file via ```open("output.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);``` and then wrote to that file using the C loop given in the question.

Comment: When creating your file, you would be wise to add `O_BINARY` to the parameters to `open`.  The default is not necessarily to open the file in binary mode, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/text-and-binary-mode-file-i-o?view=msvc-160

Comment: @Paul Sanders Is that also the case when using WSL? ```O_BINARY``` seems to be unrecognized.

Comment: I admit didn't go through the whole post, but text and binary modes translate special characters differently ('\n' for example on Windows will be translated as 2 bytes in binary mode aka "\r\n", but as 1 char in text mode). May worth checking that.

Comment: @AlexSnyder No it isn't.  Linux doesn't [need to] do any translation of line-endings.  If I'd known you were using WSL, I wouldn't have commented.

Comment: @HarryK That's definitely a good point, but I don't think that's the issue. The C program only ever wrote floating point numbers to the .txt file and didn't include any newline characters.

Comment: @PaulSanders It's my fault for not specifying. It's good to know about O_BINARY though cause I didn't even know it was a thing, so thank you for that.

Comment: But you said your text file lists 3 doubles per **line**. In any case, try comparing the 2 files (text and binary) with a hex editor, ideally with much less sample data, and you'll see if that is the problem or not (put otherwise, just get it out of the way before moving on).

Comment: I checked the binary version of the file with the hex editor and it doesn't have any newline characters inside of it. It's just a series of 64-bit floats one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

So I opened the binary text file inside a hex editor, and I didn't find any newline characters... But I did notice something interesting happening at the very end of the file. Towards the end of the file, there were actual numbers in ASCII plaintext instead of in binary. The plaintext numbers were snippets of data from the plaintext file that I had. I'm not sure how some of that data got mixed in with the binary data, but after deleting the file and rerunning my C program it outputted the binary file as expected.